# Google finance wpf graph/chart alike control?

Tags: wpf, charts, google-finance

Does anyone know a WPF control/app that functions like the google Finance graph/chart?

Thank you.

Comment: I've seen it done before, but not in a one size fits all control.

Comment: Probably not exactly a one size fits all, do you happen to know if it's open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFSLChart.aspx) article on CodeProject. It is exactly about what you are asking. Author makes standard Chart control to look and behave like Google chart.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [amCharts Stock Chart for WPF & Silverlight](http://wpf.amcharts.com/stock).

Comment: Hi Alan, do you happen to know something similar but open source? Thanks.

Comment: No. Why do you need it to be open source? You can use amCharts for free and if you must have a source you can buy a license with source code.

Comment: It's because I'm working on a client's app that requires to  have a custom graph control that functions like Google Finance, but the client want the complete code and amCharts's license requires that the code can't be shared with third-party.